# Navision / Shopify SKU

Tags: python, excel, shopify, navision

I've around 19.000 products/variants in Shopify. All the 19.000 variants i've created in Shopify have no SKUs.
I've created all variants in Navision with unique SKUs and now I need to add the SKUs from NAV to the 19.000 variants in Shopify.
The product titles is not the same in Nav and Shopify, so there is really nothing that connects the products from Nav and Shopify.

Do I need to manuel copy paste the SKUs from NAV to Shopify or is there a is there an easier way?

Comment: What kind of black magic are you searching for?

Comment: You need someway to know which variant corresponds to which, for example title or something else. Once you have that you will need to create a custom script (private app) to update each variant.

Comment: Have you tried exporting your products and variants from Navision and importing to Shopify?